# Does index still exists in these situations?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have some questions about index.

First, if I use a index column in WITH clause, dose this column still works as index column in main query?

For example,

```
WITH TEST AS (
SELECT EMP_ID
FROM EMP_MASTER
)

SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE EMP_ID >= '2000'
```

'EMP_ID' in 'EMP_MASTER' table is PK and index for EMP_MASTER consists of EMP_ID.

In this situation, Does 'Index Scan' happen in main query?

Second, if I join two tables and then use two index columns from each table in WHERE, does 'Index Scan' happen?

For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1 AND
      A.COL1 > 200 AND
      B.COL1 > 100
```

Index for table A consists of 'COL1' and index for table B consists of 'COL1'.

In this situation, does 'Index Scan' happen in each table before table join?

If you give me some proper advice, I really appreciate that.

Comment: You should just run `EXPLAIN` on the queries to see what is happening.

Comment: Don't forget that a table can have multiple indexes, and those indexes can cover multiple columns.

Comment: The answer could be phrased like this: If the indexes exist, the optimizer may or may not choose to use them (based on several considerations). However, neither the `with` clause nor the presence of predicates in the `where` clause of a join will *prevent* the optimizer from using the indexes. I believe that was really your question - do either the `with` clause by itself, or the join by itself, for no additional reason, prevent the use of indexes? The answer is an emphatic "no". If you had real-life cases where indexes were not used, you must look for other causes.

Answer (score 2):

First, SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  That is, a SQL query describes the result set, not the specific processing.  The SQL engine uses the optimizer to determine the best execution plan to generate the result set.

Second, Oracle has a reasonable optimizer.

Hence, Oracle will probably use the indexes in these situations.  However, you should look at the execution plan to see what Oracle really does.

Comment: Thank you for giving me great advice. I want to ask first question one more for double check. As I wrote down, I made a virtual table('TEST' table) using WITH. This virtual table is made with physical table('EMP_MASTER' table). This virtual table has 'EMP_ID' column and this column is PK and first index column in 'EMP_MASTER' table. In this situation, can optimizer act like "Right now, EMP_ID column is from virtual table('TEST' table) but that column is first index column in physical table('EMP_MASTER'table). So, it will be reasonable to use index."?

Comment: Also, I really want to check execution plan  but I can't check that in my situation. That's why I'm asking this.

Comment: @WooseokChoi . . . What gets executed is a *directed acyclic graph* (DAG).  This has little relationship to the query and looks quite different from the query.  Oracle's optimizer is often smart enough to determine that the filtering can use the index -- no promises because optimizers can be finicky and can get confused -- but often it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

> First, if I use a index column in WITH clause, dose this column still works as index column in main query?

Yes. A CTE (the `WITH` part) is a query just like any other - and if a query references a physical table column used by an index then the engine will use the index *if it thinks it's a good idea*.

> In this situation, Does 'Index Scan' happen in main query?

We can't tell from the limitated information you've provided. An engine will scan or seek an index based on its heuristics about the distribution of data in the index (e.g. `STATISTICS` objects) and other information it has, such as cached query execution plans.

> In this situation, does 'Index Scan' happen in each table before table join?

As it's a range query, it probably would make sense for an engine to use an index scan rather than an index seek - but it also *could* do a table-scan and ignore the index if the index isn't selective and specific enough. Also factor in query flags to force reading non-committed data (e.g. for performance and to avoid locking).